# I'm not able to figure why the following code is giving me none?

Tags: python

Code to run smallest divisor:

```
def smallesteuler():
    t=0
    result=[]
    for no in range(11,10000):
        for i in range(1,11):
            if (no%i==0):
                t=t+1
            if(t==20):
                return result.append(no)
        t=0
print (smallesteuler())
```

Comment: `list.append()` return `None`.

Comment: You're returning the result of an `append()`, which is always `None`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Euler problem 5 - find the least common multiple of 1..20.

Your code can be rewritten as

```
def euler5(upto=20):
    """
    Find the least common multiple of 1..upto
    """
    num = upto
    while True:
        if all(num % factor == 0 for factor in range(2, upto+1)):
            return num
        else:
            num += 1
```

however a much more efficient solution would be

```
from fractions import gcd
from functools import reduce

def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)

def euler5(upto=20):
    return reduce(lcm, range(1, upto+1))
```

The first solution is O(n!), the second is O(n**2).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to collect the first 20 numbers that satisfy `no%i==0`. You'll have to append those numbers to `result`, and then `return result`.

```
def smallesteuler():
    t=0
    result=[]
    for no in range(11,10000):
        for i in range(1,11):
            if (no%i==0):
                result.append(no)
                t=t+1
            if(t==20):
                return result

print (smallesteuler())
```